# Convert Ruby function to Java 9

Tags: java, ruby

I have the following Ruby function which needs to be converted to Java 9:

```
def with_size(data, format='L') # L = 32 bit unsigned integer
  [ [ data.bytesize ].pack(format), data ].join
end
```

data is a String.
I guess that bytesize can be done in Java by using

```
data.getBytes().length
```

But how can the packing part of the array with the given format be done? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the downvotes! Helping is overrated today...
Meanwhile i've found the solution and i am posting the method in use:

```
private String pack(int value, int allocateBytes, ByteOrder byteOrder, String charsetName) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(allocateBytes);
    buf.order(byteOrder);
    byte[] bytes = buf.putInt(value).array();
    String result = new String(bytes, charsetName);
    return result;
}
```

Ruby/PHP's pack('L') call for instance can be imitated by calling the Java method as follows:

```
pack(myString.getBytes().length, 4, ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN, "UTF-8");
```